# redesign a shared memory distributed system with message passinig

Tags: shared-memory, distributed-system, message-passing

As we know, we can design a distributed system using shared memory model or message passing.

I know the difference between these two models, but I want to know that can any distributed system designed with one of these two models be designed with the other one?

Thanks.